# What models/algorithms besides variational autoencoders can I use to transform a discrete input into a differentiable latent space?

Tags: natural-language-processing, algorithm-request, variational-autoencoder, model-request

Let's say I have a discrete input and want to transform it into a differentiable latent space. What models/algorithms besides variational autoencoders can I use?

Answer (score 1):

I think any kind of [matrix factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_factorization_(recommender_systems)) technique would do the trick.
You can find a lot of [resources](https://cla2019.github.io/embedmatrix.pdf) related to natural language processing about it. Of course everything is applicable outside the NLP realm.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I will look into the resources you provided. My idea is indeed that I want to apply this to NLP. So let's say I want to project whole sentences into the latent space through matrix factorization, do small, linear movements in that latent space always lead to a meaningful result?

Comment: I am asking because I want the latent space to be differentiable.